# Parse session id to laravel blade Component

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to migrate from livewire to laravel blade components. And I have a problem with parsing a variable to nested component.

on livewire everything works well.

I have view organized this way:

Route goes to controller which return a layout view.
Layout have two components x-header and x-footer.
In x-footer component i have another component x-botman.

x-botman needs a variable $session.

In app/View/Components/botman.php I've tried few ways to send session to view:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class botman extends Component
{
/**
 * Session id.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $session; // to be able to get it from <x-botman :session="$session" />

/**
 * Create a new component instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($session)
{
    // to be able in both ways if $session is sended by tag or load it directly from 
    // Session::getId()

    if (!isset($session)) {
        $this->session = ['session' => Session::getId()];
    } else {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
 */
public function render()
{
    return view('components.botman', ['session' => Session::getId()]);
}
}
```

I also tried inside component footer.blade.php and have code from botman.php in footer.php

```
<x-botman :session="$session" />
```

All time I get error 500 becouse variable $session not exist in botman.blade.php

My working livewire send variable just in return view and it works, but on components it's not:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Livewire\Component;

class Botman extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.botman', ['session' => Session::getId()]);
    }
}
```

What is easiest way to parse variable to nested component?

PHP 8.1.11 || Laravel 9.30.0

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ Session::get('error')}}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: It's not showing up so session have no errors

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.